# Java Eclipse 2018-9 version does not work on Raspbian Stretch

Tags: java, raspberry-pi3, raspbian

I recently bought the Raspberry Pi 3 b + version, installed the Java 8 191 version and unpacked it after receiving 'eclipse-jee-2018-09-linux-gtk.tar.gz' from the Eclipse official website And when I hit the executable file, I get no response.
Why are you doing this?

Note that both 32-bit and 64-bit versions can not run.

Comment: maybe the classpath is not set properly. Tyr to run it from the command line using sudo and pate the output here.

Comment: @zipo13 what mean? Tell me more.

Comment: eclipse-jee-2018-09-linux-gtk.tar.gz is not an executable. It's the installation file. Did you install eclipse already and you are trying to run it or you are still at the eclipse-jee-2018-09-linux-gtk.tar.gz stage?

Comment: @zipo13 I know it's not an executable file. What I'm saying is that you can not run the eclipse.exe file by clicking on it and clicking Run.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Eclipse via apt-get:
open the terminal and run these commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install eclipse
```

once the installation is over and went without errors you should see the Eclipse icon under the programming section of the start menu.

[image: Eclipse under RP 3]

Comment: made a new answer for your case as you are right and the other answer is for SE

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to use the EE and the tar ball.
Open the terminal and locate the tar.gz file.
I'm assuming you are going to install it on /usr/local

then do:

```
 cd /usr/local
 sudo tar xzvf eclipse-jee-2018-09-linux-gtk.tar.gz
 cd /usr/bin
 sudo ln -s /usr/local/eclipse/eclipse
```

To make sure it works:

```
ls -ld /usr/bin/eclipse
```

You should get something like `/usr/bin/eclipse -> /usr/local/eclipse/eclipse`

Now you should be able to create a shortcut or open the terminal and type:

```
eclipse&
```

To load it.

Tell me how it goes.

Comment: What is the output you get when you run eclipse from the terminal?